# Passing data from Angular service to controller and refreshing view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a bootstrap list:

```
<div class="ajax_company_list" ng-app="app">
    <div class='list-group' ng-controller="PolicyController as policyCtrl">
         <a href="#" class='list-group-item' ng-repeat="company in policyCtrl.companies">{{company.primary_name}}
         </a>               
         <div id="loadingIcon" class='list-group-item'>
              Loading...
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Angular Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('PolicyController', ['$scope', 'CompanyService', function($scope, CompanyService) {

    $scope.companies = [

    {
        policy_number: 12345,
        primary_name: "test"
    }

    ];

    $scope.getCompanies = function() {

        CompanyService.fetchCompanies()
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.companies = data.companies;

            })

        }

    }]);

app.factory('CompanyService', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {

        fetchCompanies: function() {

            return $http.get('http://spoonerinc:8886//json/glmod_Spooner-Inc?pagenum=1');

        }

}

}]);
```

I basically have 2 questions.  If I set $scope.companies equal to an array of objects, it does not show up but if I change $scope.companies to this.companies, it starts working again. Why is this?

2nd question, I can see the service call running in my net tab and can console.log the data and it reads fine.  But it is not updating my actual list at all and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I am fairly new to Angular so if there is any advice on how I can do my code better, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the `"Controller As"` syntax, which effectively publishes the entire controller object to the scope.

What happens under the hood looks something like this:

```
function myCtrl($scope){

  $scope['someAlias'] = this;

}
```

If you are going to use the controller as syntax, it's best to use a more object based approach instead of pushing things onto the `$scope`

**Either on the prototype:**

```
function myCtrl(companiesService){
   this.companiesService = companiesService;
   this.init();
}

myCtrl.prototype = {
  init:function(){
    var _this = this;

    _this.companiesService.get()
      .then(function(result){
         _this.companies = result.data;
      });
  }
};
```

**Or as closure style object:**

```
function myCtrl(comapniesService){
   var ctrl = {};

   function init(){
      companiesService.get()
      .then(function(result){
         ctrl.companies = result.data;
      });
   }

   return ctrl;
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe this was the issue the whole time.  This solved both answers at the same time, I will accept when I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, I think your problem is here:

`ng-repeat="company in policyCtrl.companies"`

You don't need to specify the controller as a prefix, since you've already declared it with ng-controller. It should be:

`ng-repeat="company in companies"`

And ng-controller to be:

`ng-controller="PolicyController"`

My guess is that the first problem will go away once you correct this.